# How to model no-sql

Tags: mongodb, nosql

This is the RDBMs approach:

I have a list of people, and so table named Person:

```
id
name
country_id
```

Then I have a table with countries, named Country:

```
id
name
```

I then insert the following rows:

```
insert into country values(1, 'Macedonia'); 
insert into country values(2, 'England');   
insert into person values(1, 'Mirko', 1);   
insert into person values(2, 'Paul', 2);
```

Then I hear that the country "Macedonia" has changed its name to "North Macedonia"

In RDBMs I would obviusly do:

```
update country set name = 'North Macedonia' where id = 1;
```

So, how does no-sql approaches this? I guess there is a document called "Person" which could have a structure like this:

```
{person_name: 'Mirko', country_name: 'Macedonia'}       
{person_name: 'Paul', country_name: 'England'}
```

When I will need to change  "Macedonia" to "North Macedonia", will I just update all the occurences of "Macedonia" to "North Macedonia"? Is this the best practice? Because I guess in no-sql you are not supposed to have a document for person and one for country. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how does no-sql approaches this? I guess there is a document
>   called "Person" which could have a structure like this:

```
>     {person_name: 'Mirko', country_name: 'Macedonia'}       
>     {person_name: 'Paul', country_name: 'England'}
```

The relationship between a country and person is One-to-Many (1-N).

But, this is a *special case* of the One-to-Many relationship. In general, the "many" side can have 100's or 1000's of documents. In this case of country and people in it, the "many" side is most likely to be in millions or even hundreds of millions.

So, the only available representation in this case is to reference the document of the "one" side of the relationship from the "many" side; that is reference "country" from "person".

The documents are likely to be like this:

*person:*

```
_id
name
age
country_id: <refers to country collection's _id>
```

*country:*

```
_id: <country's unique identifier>
country_name
total_population
```

> When I will need to change "Macedonia" to "North Macedonia", will I
>   just update all the occurences of "Macedonia" to "North Macedonia"? Is
>   this the best practice? Because I guess in no-sql you are not supposed
>   to have a document for person and one for country. Am I right?

To change a country's name, you just update the country collection's document with the changed country name.

**NOTE:** This case is *specific* to One-to-Many relationship with many side having *very large numbers* (often referred as One-to-Zillions or One-to-Squillions). Also, note that the design will be different when the "many" side has lesser number of documents (in 1-N relationships).